# JQuery not seeing "value" property

Tags: jquery, html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following function:

```
$(function () {
    $(".techdropdown").change(function () {
        var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown").val();
        window.alert(selectedTech);
        $.post("/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate, function () { document.location = "/CalloutAdmin/Index/"; });
    });
});
```

And a dropdownlist as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
    @Html.DropDownList("TechnicianId", null, String.Empty, new { id = item.CalloutId, @class = "techdropdown" })
}
```

Now what is BIZARRE is the JQuery detects the value property and displays it (selectedTech) with the FIRST dropdown created by the foreach loop, but the other dropdowns straight after seem to send no value property.

I have checked at runtime and the select options most definitely do have the correct value properties, but JQuery just doesn't see them. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here is my HTML for the table containing my dropdowns:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
                <tr style="background-color: #e6e6e6;">
                    <th>
                        Client Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">
                        Technician Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date/Time Logged
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Job Status
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Technician Status
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Michael Barnett
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            Craig

                            <select class="techdropdown" id="7" name="TechnicianId"><option value="">Choose technician...</option>
<option value="1">Mike</option>
<option value="2">Craig</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            2013/08/07 01:27:50 AM
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ASSIGNED
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Edit/7">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Details/7">Details</a> |
            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Delete/7">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Michael Barnett
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">


                            <select class="techdropdown" id="8" name="TechnicianId"><option value="">Choose technician...</option>
<option value="1">Mike</option>
<option value="2">Craig</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            2013/08/07 01:28:19 AM
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            UNASSIGNED
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Edit/8">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Details/8">Details</a> |
            <a href="/CalloutAdmin/Delete/8">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: tried that, same issue.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Emmm, are you sure about this signature of `DropDownList` ?

Comment: signature? what do you mean

Comment: Well that parameters that `@Html.DropDownList` is expecting are not really matching the ones you're providing ?

Comment: well can you help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another approach of binding a drop down list. Say you have the following model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    // this will hold the value that we select
    public int SelectedCalloutId { get; set; }

    // these are the actual items
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Technicians { get; set; }

    // add other properties needed for your view
}
```

Here is sample controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // or you know fetch them from your data source
        var technicians = new List<Technician>
        {
            new Technician {TechnicianId = "SOME_ID_1", CalloutId = 123},
            new Technician {TechnicianId = "SOME_ID_2", CalloutId = 321},
            new Technician {TechnicianId = "SOME_ID_3", CalloutId = 234}
        };

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options = technicians.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x.TechnicianId, Value = x.CalloutId.ToString()});

        return View(new TestViewModel {Technicians = options});
    }
```

Then finally in your view:

```
@model YourApp.Models.TestViewModel    
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCalloutId, Model.Technicians, new { @class = "techdropdown"})
```

This will generate more or less the following html:

```
<select class="techdropdown" id="SelectedCalloutId" name="SelectedCalloutId">
    <option value="123">SOME_ID_1</option>
    <option value="321">SOME_ID_2</option>
    <option value="234">SOME_ID_3</option>
</select>
```

Then of course on your client side:

```
$("#SelectedCalloutId").change(function () {
    // this now has a value
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
});
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the last part: http://jsfiddle.net/4K2TD/

Comment: Still doesn't help.. JQuery does not detect the values of anything other than the first dropdownlist on the page.

Comment: @barnacle.m I've just tested it - Included a fiddle -> Check my edit.

Comment: I'm trying your method, I changed the fiddle to include multiple dropdownlists of the same class and it stops working...

Comment: @barnacle.m Hmmm, here is a fiddle with multiple dropdowns -> http://jsfiddle.net/qCcJA/1/

Comment: @barnacle.m Sure, go on :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34987/discussion-between-barnacle-m-and-dimitar-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

Try add "option:selected" as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $(".techdropdown").change(function () {
        var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown option:selected").val();
        window.alert(selectedTech);
        $.post("/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate, function () { document.location = "/CalloutAdmin/Index/"; });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't help... JQuery does not detect the values of anything other than the first dropdownlist on the page.

Answer (score -1):

looks like your javascript is a bit whacky.

```
var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown").val();
```

this will take first element with class "techdropdown" and return its value.

if you want value of the dropdown which triggered the change event then you will need:

```
var selectedTech = $(this).val();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".techdropdown").change(function () {
        var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown").selected.val();
        window.alert(selectedTech);
        $.post("/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate, function () { document.location = "/CalloutAdmin/Index/"; });
    });
});
```